# SQL after a query, how to get difference between two records?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the difference between two records after a query.

This is the query:

```
select count(t.customerid) as NumberofCustomers, st.regionid, v.vendorid
from region r join store st
on r.regionid = st.regionid
join salestransaction t 
on st.storeid = t.storeid
join soldvia s
on t.tid = s.tid
join product p
on s.productid = p.productid
join vendor v
on p.vendorid = v.vendorid
where v.vendorid = 2
group by st.regionid, v.vendorid
```

This is what the query produces:

```
NumberofCustomers   regionid    vendorid
     495               1            2
     329               2            2
```

How could I get the difference between the NumberofCustomers in row1 and row2?
I have tried to use difference achieve this, but it did not give me the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that you have exactly two rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff beat me to it. That's funny that we thought about the same thing right away

Comment: Because there are only two regions

Comment: @UKcats82, ideally you would like to target each part of your substraction (each `NumberofCustomers`) in a separate sub-query (a, b) so you can substract them from above: `select a.NumberofCustomers - b.NumberofCustomers from ...`. It would give you a better view over records unicity.

Comment: @UKcats82, relying on what you know about the data is extremely bad practice. SQL design and development's pilars are database architecture, and it is best to rely on it *only*. By this I understand that, unless there's a constraint or a trigger enforcing the fact that there are 2 rows and 2 rows only, you should assume there might be 1, 3 or more one day, for a good reason or not. If `regionid` is unique, then name it explicitely in a subquery `where` condition to ensure the subquery returns 1 row, and exactly the one you want.

Comment: I understand that. I am asking how to find the difference between two records. Does it matter how many rows there are in the table? I just want to find the difference between these two specifically.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is weird. But I have funny and weird solution for you:

```
SELECT t.*,
   IF(@prev IS NULL, t.NumberofCustomers, (t.NumberofCustomers- @prev)) difference,
   @prev := t.NumberofCustomers
FROM )
select count(t.customerid) as NumberofCustomers, 
   st.regionid, v.vendorid
from region r join store st
on r.regionid = st.regionid
join salestransaction t 
on st.storeid = t.storeid
join soldvia s
on t.tid = s.tid
join product p
on s.productid = p.productid
join vendor v
on p.vendorid = v.vendorid
where v.vendorid = 2
group by st.regionid, v.vendorid ) t
```

Comment: It is a weird question. Here is another one, how would you do the same thing in SSMS? I am trying to become proficient in both and just want to see it because it is a unique question/answer.

Comment: could you explain me or give a link to the definition of SSMS? because it sounds new to me

Comment: Its just sql server management studio (SSMS). I thought that it was common to call it SSMS, but I could be wrong for sure.

Comment: So you use mysql, but you want sql solution as well? why?

Comment: Just because I like seeing differences between and its unique and I would like to know how to do it in each. I'm a loser, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two regions, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select v.vendorid,
       sum(st.regionid = 1) as NumRegion1,
       sum(st.regionid = 2) as NumRegion2,
       (sum(st.regionid = 1) - sum(st.regionid = 2)) as diff
from region r join
     store st
     on r.regionid = st.regionid join
     salestransaction t 
     on st.storeid = t.storeid join
     soldvia s
     on t.tid = s.tid join
     product p
     on s.productid = p.productid join
     vendor v
     on p.vendorid = v.vendorid
where v.vendorid = 2
group by v.vendorid;
```

The returns the numbers all in one row, rather than in two rows.